# std::map vs. self-written std::vector based dictionary

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, vector, stdmap

I'm building a content storage system for my game engine and I'm looking at possible alternatives for storing the data.  Since this is a game, it's obvious that performance is important. Especially considering various entities in the engine will be requesting resources from the data structures of the content manager upon their creation.  I'd like to be able to search resources by a name instead of an index number, so a dictionary of some sort would be appropriate.

What are the pros and cons to using an std::map and to creating my own dictionary class based on std::vector?  Are there any speed differences (if so, where will performance take a hit?  I.e. appending vs. accessing) and is there any point in taking the time to writing my own class?

For some background on what needs to happen:
Writing to the data structures occurs only at one time, when the engine loads.  So no writing actually occurs during gameplay.  When the engine exits, these data structures are to be cleaned up.  Reading from them can occur at any time, whenever an entity is created or a map is swapped.  There can be as little as one entity being created at a time, or as many as 20, each needing a variable number of resources.  Resource size can also vary depending on the size of the file being read in at the start of the engine, images being the smallest and music being the largest depending on the format (.ogg or .midi).

Comment: How many items are we talking about? 100? 1'000? 100'000? Most algorithms are fast when N is small.

Comment: At the current moment, I don't know.  The number of resources are going to build as the game is built.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Map: `std::map` has guaranteed logarithmic lookup complexity. It's usually implemented by experts and will be of high quality (e.g. exception safety). You can use custom allocators for custom memory requirements.

Your solution: It'll be written by you. A vector is for contiguous storage with random access by position, so how will you implement lookup by value? Can you do it with guaranteed logarithmic complexity or better? Do you have specific memory requirements? Are you sure you can implement a the lookup algorithm correctly and efficiently?

3rd option: If you key type is `string` (or something that's expensive to compare), do also consider `std::unordered_map`, which has *constant*-time lookup by value in typical situations (but not quite guaranteed).

Comment: So my best option then is either of the two maps.  And yes, my key will be a string, so I will definitely be looking into the unordered_map.

Comment: You would *definitely* be insane to use `std::map` keyed on `string` in a performance-critical scenario. The simply act of comparing strings for the ordering is way too expensive. The unordered containers are a pretty good idea in general whenever you don't need your elements to be ordered!

Comment: That sounds perfect for this scenario, then!

Comment: @Kerrek: "definitely insane to use std::map keyed on string in performance-critical scenario"... Yes in this usage, but not for the reasons you imply.  You'd be insane not to quickly implement & benchmark the alternatives with-in your actual environment.  String comparison for strings that often vary in the first few characters is cheap, while hashing can be expensive.  The number of entries and variability of strings are key factors.  Anyway, a `std::map` will never be as fast as a `std::binary_search` on a pre-sorted `std::vector`, which should be seen as the alternative to `unordered_map`.

Comment: @Tony: If your map is constant, then a sorted vector plus `lower_bound` is definitely preferable to a map, sure. It really depends on your needs. And agreed, you should benchmark and compare, so let's say that you'd be insane not to include `unordered_map` among the candidates :-)

Comment: A nitpick: The fact that `std::map` is written by experts and is of high quality does not mean that it's fast; it's not (and was not designed to be fast). The asymptotics are fine, but it's constant factor for these asymptotics is pretty bad.

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` is written with performance in mind anyway, whilst it does have some overhead as they have attempted to generalize to all circumstances, it will probably end up more efficient than your own implementation anyway. It uses a red-black binary tree, giving all of it's operations ***O***[log n] efficiency (aside from copying and iterating for obvious reasons).

How often will you be reading/writing to the map, and how long will each element be in it? Also, you have to consider how often will you need to resize etc. Each of these questions is crucial to choosing the correct data structure for your implementation.

Overall, one of the std functions will probably be what you want, unless you need functionality which is not in a single one of them, or if you have an idea which could improve on their time complexities.

EDIT: Based on your update, I would agree with *Kerrek SB* that if you're using C++0x, then `std::unordered_map` would be a good data structure to use in this case. However, bear in mind that your performance can degrade to linear time complexity if you have conflicting hashes (this cannot happen with `std::map`), as it will store the two pair's in the same bucket. Whilst this is rare, the probability of it obviously increases with the number of elements. So if you're writing a huge game, it's possible that `std::unordered_map` could become less optimal than `std::map`. Just a consideration. :)

Comment: @Shaktal: "While [collisions are] rare, the probably...increases with the number of elements." Not unless your table size is fixed. In practice, `unordered_map` will periodically grow the table and maintain a ratio of size to capacity, which - for a good hash algorithm - defines the collision proneness. Summarily - a good hash algorithm enables constant collision proneness (hence O(1)) whereas map / binary-search gets worse as per O(log2N), though unless there are > billions/trillions of elements the big-O efficiency may not counterbalance the hashing costs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the speed guarantee of `std::map` as well as the low memory usage of `std::vector` you could put your data in a `std::vector`, `std::sort` it and then use `std::lower_bound` to find the elements.

Comment: A sorted vector is a good idea if you perform few or no insertions and deletions, but rather only lookups. It's a good alternative to keep in mind! With string keys, I'm veering towards the `unordered_map` anyway, though, to avoid the comparisons of strings.

Comment: +1 The question stipulates load-time table population, so this is a solid good option.  `std::binary_search` and `std::upper_bound` are also relevant depending on exact needs.